# Compare a time to a range of times and return before, during, or after

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, range

I am creating a status on a device that will set an indicator color for that device based on how long it's been since the device sent back a reading. This is my current solution:

```
def indicator(device)
  # ...
  time = latest_event_time(device.id)

  case
  when time < 12.hours.ago
    :red
  when time.between?(12.hours.ago, 2.hours.ago)
    :yellow
  when 2.hours.ago < time
    :green
  else
    :gray
  end
end

private

def latest_event_time(dev_id)
  # Get latest event time from database
end
```

I would love to be able to simply check if the `time` is before, during, or after a specified time range, maybe like this:

```
time <=> (2.hours.ago...12.hours.ago)
```

Is there a method I'm missing, or another, cleaner way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you consider this an improvement, but:

```
color = [ [12, :red], [2, :yellow], [0, :green] ].find do |n, c| 
  n.hours.ago >= time
end.last
```

Comment: A small problem, I think.  What if `time = Time.now + 3600`?

Comment: Well, if a device is reporting that its last update was in the future, OP may want to do something different..

Comment: To the charge of reading questions with insufficient care, I plead guilty.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I like @CarySwoveland's use of a hash better, but I like your numbering better, since I don't need to optimize for an event in the future, as you noted.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the `<=>` operator for [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html):

```
class Range
  # return index into a 3-element array for before, in, and after
  def <=>(x)
    x < self.begin ? 0 : include?(x) ? 1 : 2
  end
end

def indicator(device)
  # ...
  time = latest_event_time(device.id) or return :gray

  [:red,:yellow,:green].at (2.hours.ago...12.hours.ago) <=> time
end
```

#### Integration

One suggestion for how to integrate the overload definition into a rails 4 project is to store the `Range` code in `lib/ext/range.rb` and add the line

```
require 'ext/range'
```

to `config/initializers/extensions.rb`. Create directories and files as necessary.

Comment: I don't see this as an improvement, since you've just translated my case statement to an if/else.

Comment: @styger See third alternative for overloading the `<=>` operator.

Comment: Upvote for an interesting solution! I'm generally not a fan of monkeypatching, so I will not use this in production code, but it is close to what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @styger That's fine - one woman's monkeypatch is another man's extension. However consider all the "monkeypatches" rails has added to the String class: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html . In my opinion you have selected a very good operator to overload `<=>` as this has the suggestion of less than (<), within (=), or greater than (>) built into it. The Range class doesn't use this operator so there is no possibility for conflict. I will use it in my projects if it ever comes up..

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def time_to_color(time)  
  { green: 2, yellow: 12, red: Float::Infinity }.find { |_,t|
    time <= t.hours_ago }.first
end
```

Perhaps I am missing something, but I don't see how `:gray` could be returned. I organized it this way to handle times in the future.

Comment: I never think to use hashes where I care about ordering.  Too many years of habits to overcome, I guess..

Comment: @MarkReed, I understand. We young guys don't have that hangup.

Comment: ouch! rubbing it in, now! :)

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I see it as slightly more obtuse than the original code, but seems headed towards something cleaner. I'll ruminate on this. Thanks!

Comment: And you're right that :gray shouldn't ever be concerned, but I'd rather explicitly set an else than leave it to chance.

Comment: styger, if you look back at this a month from now, you'll wonder why you thought it obtuse. Regarding your following comment, I suggest you never add anything that is not needed. By adding `:gray` you're telling the reader (including yourself, if you come back to the code in future) that it's there for a reason, causing the reader to waste time puzzling over it. It won't help your rep as a coder, either.